# Is there an easier way to figure the query out

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a movie table which has year and movie details like title , movie id( mid) and a table m_cast where i have all the actors in that movie.

I would like to get all the actors who have never been unemployed for more than 3 years. ( Assuming actors are unemployed between two consecutive movies)

i code i came up with is

```
select a.yr1 y1 ,  b.yr2 y2 , a.yr1 - b.yr2 diff from 
(select substr(substr(trim(year),-5),0,5) yr1 , * from movie m inner join m_cast p on m.mid = p.mid order by pid , yr1) a ,
(select substr(substr(trim(year),-5),0,5) yr2 , * from movie m inner join m_cast p on m.mid = p.mid order by pid, yr2) b on a.yr1 > b.yr2
where not exists 
(select count(*) from movie m inner join m_cast p on m.mid = p.mid
and cast(substr(substr(trim(year),-5),0,5) as integer) < a.yr1 and cast(substr(substr(trim(year),-5),0,5) as integer) > b.yr2)
```

Self join itself takes a lot of time. And lag and lead functions do not work in SQLite version i am using.

Comment: You need to show the specific schema for both `m_cast` and `movies`. I can say, though, that your query is way too complicated.

Comment: We really would need to see sample data in order to help you here.

Comment: In the absence of any useful sample data and actual table definitions... Look up "gaps and islands" to get some ideas.

Comment: Are looking for actors that appeared in movies in at least four consecutive years? So an actor with movies in 1930, 1931, 1931, 1940, 1941, 1941, 1942, 1943, 1943, 1950 would be in your results, because 1940-1943 makes four years?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the movie table has a column called year, and a column to identify the actor's name. Something like : year int, actorId int

The fastest way to run your query is to filter the last 3 years from your movie table and then to group by your actors the distinct count of years.

Example after filtering 
ActorId Year
1.            2018
1.            2018
1.            2017
2.            2016
2.            2017
2.            2018

Then group by and select distinct :
Select actorId from movieTable group by actorId having count (distinct (Year)) =3

And that will only return the actors who have worked in the last 3 years. Once you have your actors id's filtered out in that column do a join to the table that holds their names.

Sorry about the format of my writing - did it from my cellphone.

Regards, 
Jorge D. Lopez